# Significance of evaluate() and aggregate() methods in GenericUDAFEvaluator class

Tags: hive

What's the use/significance of evaluate() and aggregate() methods in the GenericUDAFEvaluator class? How is it difference from what merge() is doing?

Any example on usage of the above would be helpful.

Usage of merge(): http://beekeeperdata.com/posts/hadoop/2015/08/17/hive-udaf-tutorial.html

Javadocs: https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDAFEvaluator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the source code helped clarify things. Here are the relevant code-snippets of the same from GenericUDAFEvaluator.class file

evaluate(): This method is ensuring to call terminatePartial() implementation in case the execution mode is PARTIAL1 or PARTIAL2, else terminate() would be invoked to output the final result.

```
public Object evaluate(AggregationBuffer agg) throws HiveException {
    if ((this.mode == Mode.PARTIAL1) || (this.mode == Mode.PARTIAL2)) {
        return terminatePartial(agg);
    }
    return terminate(agg);
}
```

aggregate(): This method is checking on execution mode to invoke iterate() or merge() alternatively.

```
public void aggregate(AggregationBuffer agg, Object[] parameters) throws HiveException {
    if ((this.mode == Mode.PARTIAL1) || (this.mode == Mode.COMPLETE)) {
        iterate(agg, parameters);
    } else {
        assert (parameters.length == 1);
        merge(agg, parameters[0]);
    }
}
```

The difference modes of execution are as follows in the lifecycle of an UDAF
    • PARTIAL1
        ○ from original data to partial aggregation data: iterate() and terminatePartial() will be called. Invoked from mapper.
    • PARTIAL2
        ○ from partial aggregation data to partial aggregation data: merge() and terminatePartial() will be called. Invoked from combiner.
    • COMPLETE
        ○ from original data directly to full aggregation: iterate() and terminate() will be called. Invoked in cases where UDAF is not spawned across map-reduce stages. i.e the call is limited only to reducer stage.
    • FINAL
from partial aggregation to full aggregation: merge() and terminate() will be called. Invoked for reduce stage of a map-reduce spanning UDAF call.